# JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 5.0 Foreignkey name in @JoinColumn is ignored when generating DDL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, ddl

I am migrating my project to Hibernate 5.0. We use a generated DDL for multiple reasons so the DDL should be exactly the same as it was before. I've got most of it working except for the `@ForeignKey` name in a `@JoinColumn` in a `@OneToMany` relationship

I have a Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "NAME", name = "IDX_CHILD_NAME") }, uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME", name = "UK_CHILD_NAME") })
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "CHILD_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CHILD_ID_SEQ")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CHILD_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CHILD_PET"))
    private List<Pet> pets;

}
```

And a Pet entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PET", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "NAME", name = "IDX_PET_NAME") }, uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME", name = "UK_PET_NAME") })
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "PET_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "PET_ID_SEQ")
public class Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PET_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;



}
```

But when I try to generate a DDL I get the following statement:

```
alter table PET add constraint FKaxwc707slbsrp6vgxyyydrvcy foreign key (CHILD_ID) references CHILD
```

When I change the annotations to include the deprecated ForeignKey of Hibernate like this

```
@OneToMany()
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "FK_CHILD_PET")
@JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID")
private List<Pet> pets;
```

I do get the desired output

```
alter table PET add constraint FK_CHILD_PET foreign key (CHILD_ID) references CHILD
```

But I want to eliminate that deprecated Hibernate ForeignKey annotations.

Any suggestions?

I also included the above code in a sample project:
https://github.com/vdmc/generate-ddl-example.git

Comment: Try the Hibernate bug database. Hibernate support for FK generation using the new JPA 2.1 functionality seems to have been a bit of a mess. See, for example , https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9436 although marked as closed in 5.0

Comment: Cheers, i read up on those issues but like you said, it should be fixed according to that issue.